# Join on LINQ relative to check list boxes

Tags: asp.net, linq, inner-join, checklistbox

I have 3 tables.

- person
- equipment
- relation between person and equipment

I have a page with a search button and a checklistbox that binds with the equipment. I want the user to be able to select one or more check list and then show people associated with the selected equipment.

```
-------------------------
table1
p_famil      p_code
ali            1
reza           2
mohamad        3
kazem          4


---------------------------------
table 2

e_code   e_title
1          home
2          car
3          job

--------------------------------
table 3
er_eq_code er_per_code
2             1
3             1
1             2
1             4
```

Comment: You really should show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: how i can attach relate pages to this post?

Comment: What do you mean? What do you want to attach? Images?

Comment: i wamnt attache the project(asp.net files)

Comment: You can only insert text, hyperlinks, and/or images into your questions.